# Update a List<T> witha SubList<T> performance (LINQ or Not)

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics, updates

I have a list which can have ~200'000 items. I need to update a fixed number of fields for, for instance 150 item, using a sub-list. This is the code I am using right now:

listItem: 200'000 item List - subListItem: 150 item List (updated)

```
listItem.Select(item =>
{
    if (subListItem.Exists(x => x.ID == item.ID))
    {
        var currentItem = subListItem.Single(x => x.ID == item.ID);
        item.FIELD_1 = currentItem.FIELD_1;
        item.FIELD_2 = currentItem.FIELD_2;
        item.FIELD_3 = currentItem.FIELD_3;
        item.FIELD_4 = currentItem.FIELD_4;
    }

    return item;
}).ToList();
```

This is working good, but performance are really poor. Have you any advice ?

UPDATED SOLUTION:

```
dictItem = listItem.ToDictionary(x => x.ID);

foreach (Item updatedItem in subListItem)
{
    Item originalItem = dictItem[updatedItem.ID];
    originalItem.FIELD_1 = updatedItem.FIELD_1;
    originalItem.FIELD_2 = updatedItem.FIELD_2;
    originalItem.FIELD_3 = updatedItem.FIELD_3;
    originalItem.FIELD_4 = updatedItem.FIELD_4;
    dictItem[updatedItem.ID] = originalItem;
}
```

Comment: @haim770 Yes it's Linq to Objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make use of a dictionary to make the item lookup much quicker, i.e.

```
var subListItemsById = subListItems.ToDictionary(x => x.ID);
foreach(var item in listItem)
{
    SubListItem subListItem;
    if(subListItemsById.TryGetValue(item.ID, out subListItem))
    {
        item.FIELD_1 = subListItem.FIELD_1;
        item.FIELD_2 = subListItem.FIELD_2;
        item.FIELD_3 = subListItem.FIELD_3;
        item.FIELD_4 = subListItem.FIELD_4;
    }
}
```

Your original `listItem` will contain the modified objects. This will only work if the items contained in `listItem` are reference types. If they are mutable structs you will need to do similar to your example:

```
var subListItemsById = subListItems.ToDictionary(x => x.ID);
var modifiedItems =  listItem.Select(item =>
{
    SubListItem subListItem;
    if(subListItemsById.TryGetValue(item.ID, out subListItem))
    {
        item.FIELD_1 = subListItem.FIELD_1;
        item.FIELD_2 = subListItem.FIELD_2;
        item.FIELD_3 = subListItem.FIELD_3;
        item.FIELD_4 = subListItem.FIELD_4;
    }
    return item;
}).ToList();
```

Comment: It would be even better if the original container was optimized to use a dictionary. This optimizes the 150x lookup, optimizing the 200.000x lookup would be even faster.

Comment: Surely both approaches would be of the same performance if the dictionaries are initialized with the correct initial capacities?

Comment: Solved it using a Dictionary for the biggest list. Check the original post for the solution

Comment: In my LINQPad tests, I found the performance to be better when using `ToDictionary` with the smaller collection, and about the same performance when using a dictionary with the correct initial capacity.

Answer (score 2):

If you need better performance, you need to use a container that is optimized for lookups. For example a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) using your ID as key.

Answer (score 1):

You can speed it up a lot by creating a dictionary as stated. However you can also keep the original list if you don't have to create a copy, reducing memory footprint.

```
var subItemLookup = subItems.ToDictionary(i => i.Id);

foreach (var item in items)
{
    SubItem subItem;
    if (subItemLookup.TryGetValue(item.Id, out subItem))
    {
        item.Field1 = subItem.Field1;
        //etc.
    }
}
```